# Currency Conversion Logic for multiple rows

Tags: t-sql, currency

I have a question regarding the currency conversion logic. Currently, we return a result set which has got many currency fields. Now, the requirement says that the users should have an option to select the output currency format

eg:

```
Account name | Actual Amount | Estimated Amount | Target Amount
XYZ          | $ 2000        | $ 456.78         | $ 890.45
ABC          | SD 2000       | SD 456.78        | SD 890.45
```

if the user now selects Yen as the output format, the result set should be

```
Account name | Actual Amount | Estimated Amount | Target Amount
XYZ          | ¥ 2233        | ¥ 42356.78       | ¥ 82390.45
ABC          | ¥ 21213000    | ¥ 41156.78       | ¥ 82390.45
```

The exchange rate is available, and I know that we could have a function call in the select statement to convert the currency columns. But, making the function call for each record increases the execution time.

Is there any other logic that could be used to improve the execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a function to do conversions, you have to know that for every single record the function will be executed. So when only look at the overhead of executing a function, you'll have as much executions as you have records.

You can better make a conversion table, where you put the conversion rate in it, and join against that one. Make sure you have a column which holds the currency in both the conversion rate table and you original table, and you are good to go. In the select statement you output a formula, like rate*Actual Amount.

Comment: Mark, Thanks for responding. However, I am not very clear on your approach. Can you please explain using an example. Please note that there could be multiple currency columns in a single row and all the columns have to be converted.

Comment: For every amount make sure you know the currency. Create a currency conversion lookup table. Join the lookup table with amounts table. Then in your select statement multiply the currency with the rate. A non optimal way of doing such (made it in less then 2 minutes) you can see in this sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24dc4/4